# Get two or more rows from Firebird DB using max

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group, firebird

I'm trying to get at least two rows from query using max. I have a query for getting all customers cars and need to combine this with last date of service and order number.

```sql
select
b.year,
b.class,
b.vin,
b.plates,
a.name,
a.street,
...
from cars b
left join customers a on a.id=b.customer
```

Now I need to get last order number and date of this order and found way to get last date using

```sql
(select max(x.order_date) from orders x where x.car=b.id)
```

How to get on the same time x.order_number from the same table?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results for that sample data. I don't understand your description of what you need.

Comment: Building on @MarkRotteveel's comment, I _think_ you could show us tables CARS(ID, MODEL), BUYERS(ID, NAME), and ORDERS(ORDER_NUM, ORDER_DATE, CAR_ID, BUYER_ID) _with sample data_.  But I don't know that that actually describes your problem.  Please show us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could do something like this:

```
select g.year,
       g.class,
       g.vin,
       g.plates,
       g.name,
       g.street,
       g.maxID,
       (select x.order_date from orders x where x.order_number = g.maxID) maxDate
  from ( 
         select b.year,
                b.class,
                b.vin,
                b.plates,
                a.name,
                a.street,
                (select max(x.order_number) from orders x where x.car=b.id) maxID
           from cars b
           left join customers a on a.id=b.customer
        ) g
```

I can't really tell if that's the more efficient way, but will do the job.